# SQL Server 2008 CTE Calculate all ways between two points

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I try lot of things with the CTE and a still have a problems 
I have a table which like this for example : ( In my table i have **6 873 368 lines** )

```
+--------+----------+---------+
| SOURCE | DEST     | DISTANCE| 
+--------+----------+---------+
|  1     | 1        |  125    | 
|  1     | 2        |  100    | 
|  1     | 3        |  002    | 
|  1     | 4        |  058    | 
|  2     | 1        |  000    | 
|  2     | 2        |  050    | 
|  2     | 3        |  125    | 
|  2     | 4        |  785    | 
|  3     | 1        |  000    | 
|  3     | 2        |  050    | 
|  3     | 3        |  125    | 
|  3     | 4        |  785    | 
+--------+----------+---------+
```

I Would like to have all the way to go grom Source : 1 to the destination 4 for example 
For somes lines it work perfectly with CTE but with the number lines i have it took too long time (more than 29min for some couple of solution ) .

I try this :

```
;WITH T_Route (CONNECTION_DEST, STEPS, WEIGTH, WAY, RESSOURCE_SRC,RESSOURCE_DEST,RESSOURCE_TYPE) 
AS
   (SELECT DISTINCT C.CONNECTION_SRC 
                   , 0
                   , 0
                   , @SRC
                   , @SRC
                   , @SRC
                   , 1
    FROM #CheminCircuit AS C
    WHERE C.RESSOURCE_SRC = @SRC

    UNION  ALL

    SELECT arrival.CONNECTION_DEST
            , departure.STEPS + 1
            , departure.WEIGTH + arrival.VOL
            , departure.WAY + ',' + arrival.RESSOURCE_DEST 
            , departure.RESSOURCE_DEST
            , arrival.RESSOURCE_DEST
            , arrival.RESSOURCE_TYPE
    FROM #CheminCircuit AS arrival
    INNER JOIN T_Route AS departure ON departure.CONNECTION_DEST = case when departure.STEPS < @STEPS then arrival.CONNECTION_SRC else 0 end -- AND arrival.RESSOURCE_SRC not like '%' + @DEST + '%' AND departure.STEPS < @STEPS
    WHERE departure.WAY NOT LIKE '%,' + arrival.RESSOURCE_DEST + '%' 
    AND (arrival.RESSOURCE_TYPE NOT IN (SELECT T.[Index] FROM Type_Ressource T WHERE T.[Index] IN (1)) OR arrival.RESSOURCE_DEST IN (@SRC,@DEST))
    )
,SHORT (WEIGTH)
AS
    (SELECT WEIGTH
     FROM T_Route
     WHERE  RESSOURCE_DEST  = @DEST)

SELECT *
FROM  T_Route AS T
```

Th output i excpeted is something like this :

```
+--------+----------+----------------+--------+--------+
| SOURCE | DEST     | DISTANCE       | TIME   |STEPS   |
+--------+----------+----------------+--------+--------+
|  1     | 4        |  1->2->3->4    |  285   | 2      |
|  1     | 4        |  1->4          |  183   | 0      |
|  1     | 4        |  1->3->4       |  185   | 1      |
|  1     | 4        |  1->2->4       |  283   | 1      |
+--------+----------+---------+------+--------+--------+
```

I just want to calculate the way i need not all the way from all the point , juste a way from A to B for example :)
Have you an idea how i can do it in less time if it's possible ?

I have tried lot of things , but i have no idea of how can i stop the CTE when reach the desire value ?

I have this result before the select * from CTE sentence :

```
    +--------+----------+----------------+--------+--------+
    | SOURCE | DEST     | DISTANCE       | TIME   |STEPS   |
    +--------+----------+----------------+--------+--------+
    |  1     | 4        |  1->2->4->3    |  285   | 2      |
    |  1     | 4        |  1->4->1       |  183   | 0      |
    |  1     | 4        |  1->3->4->2->1 |  185   | 1      |
    |  1     | 4        |  1->2->4       |  283   | 1      |
    +--------+----------+---------+------+--------+--------+
```

But i would like to stop the result durring the CTE to the dest : 4
Thank you :)

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using.... (please update tags accordingly)

Comment: Sorry i haven't precise , i'm using sql server 2008

Comment: The CTE calculate all the way and took too long time with this way , i try to modify the inner join in the cte but with no result

Comment: Just glancing at the query, the biggest performance killers will most likely be your join and where clauses, particularly the `NOT LIKE` being non-sargable (starts with a `%`), but you may not be able to get rid of that. CTEs do suffer in large datasets, so changing the query to use an indexed temp table with a `while` loop to do the recursion may not be as pretty, but could well speed things up.

Comment: But i'm not sure if my inner join statement is correct or my where clause

Comment: If i add a index to the temps table will the CTE be more quick ? Or i can use a while loop to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

I like your thinking with the CTE, but doing a `NOT LIKE '% + ..` is very inefficient.

I've had a go at using another approach for this comparison using binary maths instead of string comparison!

Basically we store the "Way" as a sum of `2^(Destination)`.
So a route that went by Destination ID 1 & 3 would be `2^1 + 2^3 = 2 + 8 = 10`.
Hopefully you can see this is an efficient way to store all the visited destinations (but not in order).
Then to see if a step has been visited in the past we compare just the bit in question

You can do this by taking `2 MOD (2^(current destinationID + 1))` (basically removing all the higher destination from the stored way binary - leaving only destinations in there with IDs less than or equal to the current destination), and check this number is less than the `2 ^ (current destination ID)`.

*Note* - Using a single field to store the binary way field will allow Ids from 0 to 30 with an integer as the datatype (`2^31 - 1` is the max number that can be stored)
So using an INT the max ID is 30
If we use a BIGINT then the max ID is 62
If we use a DECIMAL(38,0) then the max ID is 125 (although its a 17 byte/ 136bit field the maxID is 10^38 -1)

Not sure how well I've explained this, so here it is in practice...

```
DECLARE @CheminCircuit TABLE([Source] INT, Dest INT, DISTANCE INT)
INSERT @CheminCircuit
        ( Source, Dest, DISTANCE )
VALUES  ( 1,1,125), (1,2,100),(1,3,2),(1,4,58),(2,1,0),
        (2,2,50),(2,3,125),(2,4,785),(3,1,0),(3,2,50),(3,3,125),(3,4,785)

DECLARE @maxSteps INT
SELECT @maxSteps = COUNT(DISTINCT Dest) 
       FROM @CheminCircuit AS cc WHERE Dest <> @src

; WITH T_Route ([Source], [Dest], Distance, Way, WayBin, STEPS)
AS(
    SELECT Source, 
       Dest, 
       DISTANCE, 
       CAST(CAST(@src AS NVARCHAR(255)) + '->' + CAST(Dest AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS NVARCHAR(255)), 
       POWER(2,Source) + POWER(2,Dest), 
       1
    FROM @CheminCircuit AS cc WHERE Source = @src AND cc.Dest <> cc.Source

    UNION ALL

    SELECT T_Route.Source, cc.Dest, 
           T_Route.Distance + cc.DISTANCE, 
           CAST( T_Route.Way + '->' + CAST(cc.Dest AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS NVARCHAR(255)), 
           T_Route.WayBin + POWER(2,cc.Dest), 
           T_Route.STEPS + 1
    FROM @CheminCircuit AS cc
        JOIN T_Route ON T_Route.Dest = cc.Source
    WHERE T_Route.STEPS < @maxSteps 
        AND T_Route.Dest <> @dst AND cc.Dest <> cc.Source 
        AND (T_Route.WayBin % POWER(2, cc.Dest+1) ) < POWER(2,cc.Dest)
)
SELECT * FROM T_Route WHERE Dest = @dst
```

this gives the desired result (more or less)

```
Source  Dest    Distance    Way         WayBin  STEPS
------  ----    --------    --          ------  -----
1       4       58          1->4        18      1
1       4       787         1->3->4     26      2
1       4       837         1->3->2->4  30      3
1       4       885         1->2->4     22      2
1       4       1010        1->2->3->4  30      3
```

You'll also notice I'm also checking that we aren't beyond the maximum number of steps in the CTE self-join

Comment: Hey :) thanks for this answer i tried it to my own table , but it returned an error , maybe due to the power with destination , i have this : Erreur de dépassement arithmétique pour le type int, valeur = 281474976710656.000000. In my table i have 6034 source and destination , maybe it's the problems ?

Comment: Hi - yes this method would only work with smaller ID values for the source and destination - as per the edit above - up to 30 for an INT, and up to 125 for a DECIMAL(38,0) . You could technically cover more IDs by having multiple fields, and splitting the values across them - but that would mean you'd need 49 fields for your data! I doubt it would work anyway at those higher IDs, as the precision would be lost. So I think maybe abandon the CTE idea and look at doing a while loop instead where you have 2 tables you build up (route, and routeItem) - copying from one to the next every iteration

Comment: NB - if you just want to stop the CTE when the destination is reached you can just add `AND departure.RESSOURCE_DEST <> @DEST` to the WHERE clause in the recursive part of the CTE

Comment: Thinking about it though it may still be possible to make this method work using a VARBINARY(8000) as the storage column, but that will need a bit more thought. I'll update the answer if I can work it out!